# Cypress test organization

Tags: e2e-testing, cypress

I have a question about Cypress test organization. 
I wanted to have your feedback on how you divide your tests ?

When you define a test with

```
it("", function() {})
```

how much do you test ? Do you limit yourself in assertions ?

I have a dataroom that in which two users can interract. One user can upload files and chat with the other, and the user 2 can only upload the files and chat.

What I need to test is :

- List item
- Upload of a document by user #1
- Removing a document by user #1
- Assert that chat gets automatic messages about the file uploaded and deleted
- user #2 can upload documents
- user #2 can close the dataroom and reopen it
- ...

The question I'm asking myself is about the number of test I should have.

Should I have one that runs the whole scenario ? 
Should I have one for each test I want to make
Should I have multiple grouping by user 
...

If you have any suggestions on how you organize your test, I would be happy to hear them !

Answer (score 0):

I like to divide my tests in separate subjects and scenario's. So a definition-file contains only 1 subject, and it contains an `it` per scenario. This way it is possible to have a failing scenario, without blocking all other scenario's.

For example, if you have a house I would separate them like this:

```js
describe ('Living room', function (){
  it('Should have a couch', function(){
    // do checks for the couch
  })
  it('Should have a media table', function (){
    // do checks for the media table
  })
})

describe ('Kitchen', function (){
  it('Should have a stove', function(){
    // do checks for the stove
  })
  it('Should have a kitchen table', function (){
    // do checks for the kitchen table
  })
})

describe ('Bathroom', function (){
  it('Should have a shower', function(){
    // do checks for the shower
  })
  it('Should have a sink', function (){
    // do checks for the sink
  })
})
```

Comment: Agree with Mr.j. And same time You can create folder like" livingRoom " and that folder can have more than one suite together.

Comment: Ok so each it should be independant and have one scenario right ? 
So that if one it fails, it cannot fail the other ones ?

Comment: that is definitely the way to go if you ask me :) if all tests are depending and the first one fails out of 10, it looks like all 10 tests are broken. But if they are all in-depending it might result in 1 out of 10 failures. So it wasn't as broken as it looked like